# Using custom Stencil tag in Kitura

Tags: kitura

Following the instructions in the Stencil documentation, I registered a simple custom tag:

```
let ns = Namespace()

ns.registerSimpleTag("contact") { context in
  return "<a href=\"/contact\">contact us</a>"
}
```

but I can't see how to pass the namespace to `render`, as `response.render` only takes a dictionary, not an actual `Context` object.

What am I missing? Is there a pre-existing namespace somewhere I should be using instead of creating one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine and change [KituraStencilTemplateEngine.swift](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine/blob/master/Sources/KituraStencilTemplateEngine.swift).

Define your *ns* namespace in *StencilTemplateEngine.render()* and change the return code line to be:

```
return try template.render(Context(dictionary: context), namespace: ns)
```

Then add a tag to your fork and use your fork as a dependency in *Package.swift*.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I need to make changes to `class StencilTemplateEngine`. I did it slightly differently from the way you suggest and now have a working solution.

Comment: @MacAvon The rationale here is that once you customize Stencil Template Engine, e.g. with custom tags, you can consider it as a different template engine. So you can create your own _Kitura-MyCustomizedStencilTemplateEngine_ repository, with its own versioning etc., and use it for your multiple Kitura apps.  _Kitura-MyCustomizedStencilTemplateEngine_ will implement [Kitura TemplateEngine protocol](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-TemplateEngine/blob/master/Sources/KituraTemplateEngine/TemplateEngine.swift) and add whatever customizations are required for Stencil, for all your Kitura apps.